# Disable (grey out) Menu Bar Items in XML Layer (Netbeans 7.2)

Tags: java, xml, menu, netbeans-7

I am very new to java programming and the NetBeans IDE platform. I am currently working on a GUI project in NetBeans IDE 7.2 and am trying to customize the Menu Bar. I found a resource that explained how to do this using the layer XML file: https://sites.google.com/a/geotoolkit.net/intviewer/using-netbeans-swing-components-walkthroughs/adding-a-menu-item-walkthrough

I have therefore coded my entire menu bar in XML using the guidelines from the provided resource under "Customizing the layer.xml file". At the current stage of my GUI development, I would like these menu bar items to be disabled (greyed out). Is there a way that I can do this just in the layer.xml file?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, after spending two days trying to figure this out, I finally post this question and figure it out almost an hour later. If anyone else is interested in learning how to do this, within the layer XML file, you will want to add the following within the file declaration that you would like to grey out:

```
    <attr name="instanceCreate" methodvalue="org.openide.awt.Actions.context"/>
    <attr name="type" stringvalue="org.netbeans.api.actions.Openable"/>
    <attr name="selectionType" stringvalue="ANY"/>
```